# How to score points based on the answers given in the entity form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a form with some question on it. Each questions has options and every option has some points attached to them. After answering all the questions the user should see the total score 
in a text box. The answers will be in a drop down menu.

Is there any way where I can attach particular weightage to each answer? Btw depending on the answer the score might be added to or subtracted from (negative scoring).

What I was actually doing was setting the option set values to the desired numbers and adding them to get the result. But I ran into trouble when two or more options had the same weightage/score and there are two options with negative marks. So now i am looking forward to a better way to handle the issue. Here is a code snippet.

```
function getValue()
{
var optionset = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_housingq1");

var value = optionset.getValue();

alert(value);

var optionset2 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_housingq2");

var value2 = optionset2.getValue();

alert(value2);

var value3 = value + value2; 

alert(value3);

Xrm.Page.getAttribute(“inmate_housing_score“).setValue(“value3”);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my code. I am using the ID value of each of the options of option set and have set the required marks as their ID. Here is my final working code.

```
function getValue()
{
var optionset = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_housingq1");
var value = optionset.getValue();
if(value==11)
{
value = value-1; 

}
else
{
value; 
}

var optionset2 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_housingq2");
var value2 = optionset2.getValue();
if(value2==11)
{

value2 = value2-1; 

}
else
{
value2; 
}

var optionset3 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_housingq3");
var value3=optionset3.getValue();

var optionset4 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_housingq4");
var value4=optionset4.getValue();

var optionset5 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_housingq5");
var value5=optionset5.getValue();

var optionset6 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_housingq6");
var value6=optionset6.getValue();

if(value6==2)
{

value6 = value6-4; 

}
else
{
value6; 
}


var optionset7 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_housingq7");
var value7=optionset7.getValue();
if(value7==1)
{
value7 = value7-2;
}
else
{
value7;
}




var optionset8 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_housingq8");
var value8=optionset8.getValue();
if(value8==1)
{
value8 = value8-2;
}
else
{
value8;
}

var result = value + value2 + value3 + value4 + value5 + value6 + value7 + value8; 

Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_housing_score1").setValue(result);

}
```